# On what basis do some people claim Krishna is really the only ultimate God?

Tags: krishna

Some people say Krsna is the ultimate supreme personality of Godhead. It is also mentioned by them that all scriptures, in fact, declare this fact.

Also, I hear that the stories, facts, and other information about other Gods is true but it's all valid on the material platform. But the ultimate reality and the only God who is omnipresent and authentic across all universes and platforms is Krsna.

What is the basis for this claim?

Comment: If you ask for One god is superior alone then it will be opinion based answer. This is against site rules and policies.  Hence closing this question

Comment: Hinduism has various sects. Each has sects project their supreme God. So no sects should be hurt and hence this question ll be closed

Comment: Yeah true. Krishna is really the only ultimate God. But Siva, Bhuvaneswari etc., are Krishna itself. So they are also the supreme authorities. Just names are different.

Comment: Krishna(incarnation of Vishnu) and Shiva, both are same, Here is the post that might help ['Shiva is Supreme Lord of Vishnu and Vishnu is Supreme Lord of Shiva'?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/where-is-the-mention-of-shiva-is-supreme-lord-of-vishnu-and-vishnu-is-supreme-l/13598#13598)

Comment: "How authentic is this information?" Not authentic at all. There are different scriptures which mention different gods as the brahman himself/herself.

Comment: Yes, Krishna is ultimate reality for Krishna's followers. Similarly, Shiva is for Shivas, Vishnu for vaishnavas and Shakti for Shaktas. And it yes there are verses which says Krishna is superior

Comment: On what basis it is not authentic @wikash_ ?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta on a subjective basis.

Comment: @wisash_ same applies to other scriptures as well

Comment: No it does not. @KrishaShweta

Answer (score 2):

Very good question asked in wrong perspective.

Your question implies that there are multiple gods and also one (and only one) ultimate god.

Before completely understanding the inherent assumptions and definitions it would be useless to refer to scriptures, as hindu scriptures, just like any other religious scriptures are interpreted differently by different sects.

```
 the ultimate reality and the only God who is omnipresent
 and authentic across all universes and platforms is Krsna
```

Very similar statement appears time and time in all of hinduism, with just the name of the god changing.

But that is understandable as the ultimate reality, which is beyond and above material world cannot be expressed in words.

Various people experienced that ultimate reality in various forms and different names. The only thing different with Lord Krishna (Krsna) is that he was called the ***Paripurna*** Avatara, or the complete Avatar.

[about avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7754/anshavatar-and-purnavatar-are-there-different-types-of-avatars)

[also about avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9678/why-is-lord-krishna-called-the-complete-vishnu-as-compared-to-his-other-incarnat)

If you want to know more about the nature of ultimate reality, read Upanishads yourself (under guidance of guru, if possible). Before experiencing the truth yourself, comparing between different gods and names will do no good.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Krishna is really the only ultimate God. This is the conclusion of all scriptures and seen in many scirptures like Bhagavata Purana, Vishnu Purana, Gita etc..

Krishna say in Gita ([7.7](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7/7))

> **mattaḥ parataraṁ nānyat** kiñcid asti dhanañ-jaya mayi sarvam idaṁ
>   protaṁ sūtre maṇi-gaṇā iva
>
> O conqueror of wealth, **there is no truth superior to Me**. Everything
>   rests upon Me, as pearls are strung on a thread.

Gopala Tapani Upanishad says:

> sac-cid-ananda-rupaya kRsnayaklista-karine namo vedanta-vedyaya gurave
>   buddhi-saksine
>
> I offer obeisances to Krsna, the form of eternity, knowledge, and
>   bliss, whose every act is wonderful, who is the object of knowledge
>   identified by the Vedanta, and who is the guru, the witness present
>   in the intelligence.

One may say: “But one can’t conlude that Vishnu is supreme, because there is a variety of opinions expressed in the various Puranas uttered by Vyasa, where Brahma and Siva are also declared to be supreme.”

But supremacy of Vishnu/Krishna is conclusion of the scriptures.

Thus in Padma Purana, Patala Khanda, 97.26 it is said:

> vyāmohāya carācarasya jagataste te purāṇāgamāstāṃ tāmeva hi devatāṃ
>   paramikāṃ jalpaṃtu kalpe vidhau  siddhāṃte punareka eva bhagavānviṣṇuḥ
>   samastāgama- vyāpāreṣu vivekināṃ vyatikaraṃ nīteṣu niścīyate
>
> व्यार्मोहाय चराचरस्य जगतस्ते ते पुराणागमास्तां तामेव हि देवतां परमिकां
>   जल्पंतु कल्पे विधौ  सिद्धांते पुनरेक एव भगवान्विष्णुः समस्तागम-
>   व्यापारेषु विवेकिनां व्यतिकरं नीतेषु निश्चीयते
>
> For bewildering the living entities of the universe, let the Puranas
>   and other scriptures speak, until the end of the kalpa, about various
>   “supreme” devatas. However, in conclusion, **Lord Vishnu alone is
>   discerned in all the scriptures and in all conduct through harmonizing
>   all statements with intelligence.**

For bewilderment of the universe composed of moving entities such as men and devatas and non-moving entities such as presiding deities of mountains, let the Puranas and other scriptures proclaim devatas such as Brahma and Siva to be supreme till the end of the kalpa. However, since there is a conclusion reached by the Brahma sutras and its commentary in the form of the Bhagavatam, through discrimination by use of direct and indirect meaning of the words, the form of Vishnu composed of unobstructed knowledge and bliss is determined to be supreme.

Thus we see in Bhagavatam ([1.18.21](http://srimadbhagavatam.org/canto1/chapter18.html)):

> athāpi yat-pāda-nakhāvasṛṣṭaṁ  jagad viriñcopahṛtārhaṇāmbhaḥ seśaṁ
>   punāty anyatamo mukundāt  ko nāma loke bhagavat-padārthaḥ
>
> **Who else would be worth the position of carrying the name of Supreme
>   Lord[Bhagavan] besides Mukunda [Lord Krishna as the one granting liberation]**
>   from whose toenails the water emanated [of the Ganges] that was
>   collected by Brahmâjî and purifies Lord S'iva and the entire universe?

The [Vishnu Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116066.html) also says that the term Bhagavan(used to literally indicate supreme) belongs to Lord Vasudeva alone. When used for others, it is used in a different sense:

> The word Bhagavat is a convenient form to be used in the adoration of
>   that supreme being, to whom no term is applicable; and therefore
>   Bhagavat expresses that supreme spirit, which is individual, almighty,
>   and the cause of causes of all things. The letter Bh implies the
>   cerisher and supporter of the universe. By ga is understood the
>   leader, impeller, or creator. The dissyllable Bhaga indicates the six
>   properties, dominion, might, glory, splendour, wisdom, and dispassion.
>   The purport of the letter va is that elemental spirit in which all
>   beings exist, and which exists in all beings[9]. **And thus this great
>   word Bhagavan is the name of Vāsudeva, who is one with the supreme
>   Brahma, and of no one else. This word therefore, which is the general
>   denomination of an adorable object, is not used in reference to the
>   supreme in a general, but a special signification. When applied to any
>   other (thing or person) it is used in its customary or general import.**
>   In the latter case it may purport one who knows the origin and end and
>   revolutions of beings, and what is wisdom, what ignorance. In the
>   former it denotes wisdom, energy, power, dominion, might, glory,
>   without end, and without defect.

Hari Vamsa states:

> vede rAmAyaNe punye bhArate bharatarShabha | Adau chAnte cha madhye
>   cha hariH sarvatra gIyate ||3-132-95
>
> In Vedas, in the Ramayana and in the sacred Bharata, O chief of
>   Bharata’s race, Hari is sung everywhere, in the beginning, the middle
>   and at the end.

Thus, Krishna says in Bhagavad Gita(15.15)

> vedaiś ca sarvair aham eva vedyo vedānta-kṛd veda-vid eva cāham
>
> I am that which is to be known in all the Vedas. I, indeed, the knower
>   of the Vedas and the author of the Vedanta.

Similarly in the Bhagavata Purana(11.21.42-43), Krishna speaks to Uddhava:

> kiṁ vidhatte kim ācaṣṭe  kim anūdya vikalpayet ity asyā hṛdayaṁ loke
>    nānyo mad veda kaścana māṁ vidhatte ’bhidhatte māṁ  vikalpyāpohyate
>   tv aham
>
> None except me knows what is really taught by the commands and
>   prohibitions as laid down in the Karmakanda ; what is really expressed
>   by the Mantras in the Devata-kanda, or what is the purpose of the
>   passages to be found in the Jnanakanda. All the Karmakandas refer to
>   me because I am the great sacrificer ; all the Mantras praise me
>   because I am the highest Devata ; and all the Jnanakanda refers to me
>   because I am the creator of the world and withdraw it again to myself.
>   Verily, I am this all. Again, Scriptures enjoin duties as my worship,
>   use Indra and all other names as my appellation, the texts that
>   prescribe, as well as prohibit acts, point to me; so, in such a state
>   none other than myself understand their true meaning.

You may also read commentary on the below [sutra](https://archive.org/stream/Sacred_Books_of_the_Hindus/SBH%2005%20-%20Vedantasutras%20of%20Badarayana%20with%20Baladevabhashya%20English%20Translation%20-%20Srisa%20Chandra%20Vasu%201934#page/n53/mode/2up):

> tat tu samanvyat
>
> (But Vishnu is the subject matter of all the Vedas) because such is
>   the appropriate interpretation of all the texts.

Comment: 'conclusion of all scriptures' - Really?!

Comment: @sv. Realistically. What is so surprising in that?

Comment: @sv. yes really. All taken together and applying the proper interpretation rules. Rejecting weaker statements in favor of stronger statements. etc...

Comment: It is ofcourse not the conclusion of all scriptures.