# Which scriptures talk about avataras and kalas?

Tags: avatars

It is said creatures have different number of kalas, but avataras have more kalas than others. The number goes until 16 for a complete avatar (like Sri Krishna). Also the quantity doesn't mean "better", because all avataras are same God taking differents bodies.

I found 2 diferent list for these 16 kalas, [on here](https://www.hindu-blog.com/2013/08/what-are-16-kalas-of-lord-krishna.html):

> 1. Daya – Compassion
> 2. Dharjya – Patience
> 3. Kshama – Forgiveness
> 4. Nyaya – Justice
> 5. Nirapeksha – Impartiality
> 6. Niraskata – Detachment
> 7. Tapasya – Meditation and Spiritual Powers
> 8. Aparchitta – Invincibility
> 9. Danasheel – Beneficience, Bestower of all wealth in the world and nature.
> 10. Saundarjyamaya – Beauty Incarnate
> 11. Nrityajna – Best of Dancers
> 12. Sangitajna – Best of Singers
> 13. Neetibadi – Embodiment of Honesty
> 14. Satyabadi – Truth Itself
> 15. Sarvagnata – Perfect master of all arts, such as poetry, drama, painting etc.
> 16. Sarvaniyanta – Controller of All

and [this other](https://www.facebook.com/bhagwatpuran.rohit/posts/262003937283390)

> 1. Annamaya
> 2. Pranamaya
> 3. Manomaya
> 4. Vigyanamaya
> 5. Anandamaya
> 6. Atishayini
> 7. Viparinabhini
> 8. Sankramini
> 9. Prabhavi
> 10. Kunthini
> 11. Vikasini
> 12. Maryadini
> 13. Sanhaladini
> 14. Ahladini
> 15. Paripurna
> 16. Swarupavasthita

[Here in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18648) it is very well explained different kinds of avataras

> **amśa, amśāmśa, āveśa, kalā, pūrṇa and paripūrṇatama (or paripūrṇa)**

but now I'm asking about 16 kalas

Comment: Related or duplicate [How do the scriptures describe some of the key features of Avataras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22701/3500)